# How do I separate spline (using bpy) to a new curve?

Tags: python, scripting, error

I have a very straight-forward code, it's not working. I wonder why does it select nothing and raise "No points selected" error. (Yes, it's a Nurbs curve, not Bezier)

```py
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.active_object

spline = obj.data.splines[0]
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
bpy.ops.curve.select_all(action='DESELECT')
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')

if spline:
    for pt in spline.points:
        pt.select = True

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
bpy.ops.curve.separate()
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that when you switch to *Edit Mode* using `bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')`, Blender enters a different mode of operation where it creates a temporary copy of the original spline data to enable editing without directly affecting the original object's data. I made a print trace and I get different addresses for the same spline in *Object Mode* and *Edit Mode*:

[image]

This script will work:

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.active_object

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
spline = obj.data.splines[0]
print("Spline Address in Object Mode:", spline)

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
spline = obj.data.splines[0]
print("Spline Address in Edit Mode:  ", spline)

bpy.ops.curve.select_all(action='DESELECT')

if spline:
    for pt in spline.points:
        pt.select = True

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
bpy.ops.curve.separate()
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
```

Comment: thank you a lot! You saved my nervous system and my PC also (￣▽￣)"

Comment: you're welcome! :)